# how to delete checked items from QTreeWidget?

Tags: qt4, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have list of QTreeWidget items with check boxes, which are child items with few top level items. I want to delete the items which are in checked state, how can I iterate the qtreewidget and delete those items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Not compiled, but hopefully you get the idea.

```
for(int topnum = 0; topnum < treeWidget->topLevelItemCount(); ++topnum)
{
    if(Qt::Checked == treeWidget->topLevelItem(topnum)->checkState(0))  //assume one column
    {
        delete treeWidget->takeTopLevelItem(topnum);
        --topnum;                       //decrement because you just removed it
    } else
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* topitem = treeWidget->topLevelItem(topnum);
        for(int childnum = 0; childnum < topitem->childCount(); ++childnum)
        {
            if(Qt::Checked == topitem->child(childnum)->checkState())
            {
                delete topitem->takeChild(childnum);
                --childnum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure I understand if the toplevel items are checked or if the children are checked, so I checked (haha) for both.